# Mocking Database when writing Nunit white box tests

Tags: unit-testing

I read one of your posts where you specify your suggested mode of writing white box tests for DAL modules as "mocking the database". Could you elaborate a little more on this approach? Does mocking a database mean that we are performing CRUD operations on a local file system or something of that order? Does the approach of mocking the database even test the CRUD operations? Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually means creating repository interfaces for data access classes (interfaces only define contracts and they do not contain any implementation). You program rest of the system using these interfaces when you want to access the database. You replace them with test doubles in your tests, so you can implement the rest of the system with unit tests before you write any data access code. Once you are done you simply implement those repository interfaces using the DAL technology/ORM of your choice.